# How can I use "emulate sh" in zsh to work with ". myscript.sh"?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I've been using `emulate sh -c ". $HOME/myscript.sh"` and it's working so far.

However, if I'm at `~` and try to do `emulate sh -c ". myscript.sh"`, I get `.: no such file or directory: myscript.sh.`. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.` builtin looks for the script passed argument in the command search path (`$PATH`) if it doesn't contain a `/`. This is true both in POSIX shells and in native zsh, so unsurprisingly it's true in zsh's sh emulation mode as well.

The `source` builtin in bash and zsh is identical to `.` except that no PATH lookup happens, a script name not containing a `/` is looked for in the current directory.

```
emulate sh -c 'source myscript.sh'
```

or

```
emulate sh -c '. ./myscript.sh'
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes much more sense.